# Altair: Scrollable bar charts when dealing with many categories

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have a dataset with a large number of categories. I'd like to show them all on the same Altair bar chart, but I don't want them all to be shown all at once. Instead I'd like to only show a subset of categories and allow the user to scroll through the list as needed.

The following code will create a horizontal bar chart with 63 rows along the y-axis. I would like to just show 10 rows at one time, but allow the user to scroll up or down along the y-axis  as desired.  Making the chart interactive in this case only enables scrolling along the x-axis (the quantitative variable).

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data('countries')

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='life_expect:Q',
    y='country:N'
).interactive()
```

[bar chart with all categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXl8Z.png)

I know that in Altair you can filter the data to only show a subset (e.g., top 10 categories), but this approach does not allow the user to decide which categories to see.

I'm also aware that this is a current limitation in Vega-Lite of interactive() not working on ordinal/nominal scales. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Similar question here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/3194